# Convert linq query to IEnumerable mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have  2 model:

```
public class RentPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public int RentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class RentType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a view model contain some property from models:

```
public class RentPriceViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I use RentPriceViewModel in an another view model like this:

```
public class PlaceDetailsViewModel
{
    public Place Place { get; set; }
    public Place_Reserve PlaceReserve { get; set; }
    public Place_Type Place_Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Place_Type> Place_Types { get; set; }
    public Aminity Aminity { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Aminity> Aminities { get; set; }
    public City cities { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<RentType> RentTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RentPrice> RentPrices { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RentPriceViewModel> RentPriceViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

and in controller
i fill this :

```
 PlaceDetailsViewModel pd = new PlaceDetailsViewModel();
 pd.RentTypes = db.RentTypes;
 pd.RentPriceViewModels = db.RentPrices.Join(db.RentTypes, rp => rp.RentTypeId, rt => rt.Id,
     (rp, rt) => new {rp.Id, rp.PlaceId, rp.Price, rt.Name, rp.Date})
     .Where(x => x.PlaceId == step4ViewModel.PlaceId).AsEnumerable();
```

but I have an error to for filling pd.RentPriceViewModels!!

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MazandVila.WebUI.Models.ViewModels.RentPriceViewModel>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

when I cast in Ienumerable also get error!

Please check and help me!

Comment: `new {rp.Id, rp.PlaceId, rp.Price, rt.Name, rp.Date}` should be replaced with `new RentPriceViewModel {Id = rp.Id, PlaceId = rp.PlaceId, Price = rp.Price, Name = rt.Name, Date = rp.Date}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is you are assigning an `anonymous` type to a property  whose type is `RentPriceViewModels`. You need to project `RentPriceViewModels` type instead:-

```
pd.RentPriceViewModels = db.RentPrices.Join(db.RentTypes, rp => rp.RentTypeId, rt => rt.Id,
      (rp, rt) => new RentPriceViewModel  { Id = rp.Id,
                                            PlaceId = rp.PlaceId, 
                                            Price = rp.Price, 
                                            Date = rt.Name, rp.Date
                                          })
      .Where(x => x.PlaceId == step4ViewModel.PlaceId).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: are you sure this works? `RentPriceViewModel` is a simple class, not a collection. See the difference between this and my comment to the OP's question.

Comment: @KingKing - Duh! I guess you are talking about the `properties` :) Surely they should be provided when projecting strong type. Thanks anyways will update :)